# Calculate with creating column names in data table on the fly

Tags: r, data.table, calculated-columns

I have problems in getting data table to create 28 new columns by calculating their value from other column names that are variables and, at the same time, fulfill some conditions.

What I am trying to achieve is to distinguish four cases:

1. Fields incumbents (ic) and newcomers (nc) == 0 => desired result = NA : this is the first if-clause and it works.
2. Fields ic are > 0, but no nc present (0) => desired result = value of ic_col (i.e. the number of newcomers): this is the second if clause and it does not work.
3. Fields ic == 0, but nc are present (>0) => desired result = 0: this is the third if clause and it works.
4. Fields ic > 1 and nc > 1 (= both are present) => desired result = the ratio of both numbers, i.e. ic_col / nc_col. This is the fourth if-clause and does not work.

As you can see I tried many different variants (if clause 2 tries to do it in one DT way), if-clause 4 tries to get the values beforehand (which, of course, does not work, since my_ic_value has all the thousands of values in it instead only the one row).
Other things I unsuccessfully tried were

```
all <- all[, ratio_col:= get(ic_col) / get(nc_col)), by=.(m_island_id_1, m_owner_id_1)]
```

Also just using the colum names does not work, because they are strings and cannot be divided:

```
all <- all[, ratio_col:= (ic_col / nc_col), by=.(m_island_id_1, m_owner_id_1)]
```

I hope the problem is somewhat clear and I am looking forward to all the data.table experts showing me how hopelessly messy my code is and how short and fast it can be done! ;-)

Thank you for your help!

Here is some data (a very small portion):

```
structure(list(m_island_id_1 = c("020d49b9580f071075cfb6f9da7a426669a56d2d", 
"020d49b9580f071075cfb6f9da7a426669a56d2d", "020d49b9580f071075cfb6f9da7a426669a56d2d"
), m_owner_id_1 = c("01d96c16a2caf720617b266ae5d053243cef0920", 
"4e25ef4cf04f023d96134856098b8104fa6a6add", "7818c5081257a837e7cfad2c1aba4d90dcd18a69"
), Sum_nc = c(2L, 2L, 2L), Sum_ic = c(4L, 4L, 4L), Sum_ic_2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), Sum_ic_3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Sum_ic_5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_7 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), Sum_ic_8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Sum_ic_10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_11 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Sum_ic_12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_13 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_14 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), Sum_ic_15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_16 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L), Sum_ic_17 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Sum_ic_18 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), 
    Sum_ic_19 = c(2L, 2L, 2L), Sum_ic_20 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_21 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), Sum_ic_22 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_23 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L), Sum_ic_24 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_25 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Sum_ic_26 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_27 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_ic_28 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), Sum_nc_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Sum_nc_4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_6 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), Sum_nc_7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Sum_nc_9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_11 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), Sum_nc_12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_13 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L), Sum_nc_14 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Sum_nc_16 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Sum_nc_17 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_18 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), Sum_nc_19 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_20 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L), Sum_nc_21 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_22 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Sum_nc_23 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_24 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_25 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), Sum_nc_26 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum_nc_27 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L), Sum_nc_28 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), inhabited = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
    FALSE), Sum_time_ic = c(3L, 1L, 0L), groupsize = c(2L, 2L, 
    2L), Ratio_nc_to_ic_16 = c(0, 0, 0), Ratio_nc_to_ic_17 = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE), Ratio_nc_to_ic_18 = c(1, 1, 1), Ratio_nc_to_ic_19 = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE), ratio_col = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Ratio_nc_to_ic_ = c(2, 2, 2), Ratio_nc_to_ic_2 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_3 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_4 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_5 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_6 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_7 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_8 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_9 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_10 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_11 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_12 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_13 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_14 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_15 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_20 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_21 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_22 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_23 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_24 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_25 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_26 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_27 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), Ratio_nc_to_ic_28 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001f487d51ef0>)
```

Here is the non-working code:

```
for (j in 2:28){
  ic_col <- paste0("Sum_ic_", j)
  nc_col <- paste0("Sum_nc_", j)
  ratio_col <- paste0("Ratio_nc_to_ic_", j)
  my_ic_value <- all[,get(ic_col)]
  my_nc_value <- all[,get(nc_col)]

  if ((ic_col == 0) & (nc_col == 0)) {
    all <- all[, ratio_col:=  NA, by=.(m_island_id_1, m_owner_id_1)] # no incumbents, no newcomers
  }
  if ((ic_col > 0) & (nc_col == 0)) {
    all <- all[, .(ratio_col=  ic_col), by=.(m_island_id_1, m_owner_id_1)] # Incumbents without newcomers
  }
  if ((ic_col == 0) & (nc_col > 0)) {
    all <- all[, ratio_col:=  0, by=.(m_island_id_1, m_owner_id_1)] # Newcomers without incumbents
  }
  if ((ic_col >= 1) & (nc_col >= 1)) {
    all <- all[, ratio_col:= (my_ic_value / my_nc_value), by=.(m_island_id_1, m_owner_id_1)] # Newcomers with incumbents
  }
}
```

Comment: You should try the new `fcase` function, see [NEWS](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/news/index.html) and [Installation](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like calculations are to be performed row-wise, hence you can drop the `by` (please correct me if I am wrong). And using matrix operations can cover the last 2 cases. And then using some indexing to handle cases 1 and 2 as follows:

```
DT[, (ratio_cols) := {
    icmat <- as.matrix(.SD[, mget(ic_cols)])
    ncmat <- as.matrix(.SD[, mget(nc_cols)])

    m <- icmat / ncmat

    #when nc_col==0
    m[is.infinite(m)] <- icmat[is.infinite(m)]

    #when ic_col==0 & nc_col==0
    m[icmat==0 & ncmat==0] <- NA_real_

    as.data.table(m)
}]
```

data:

```
#where dat is your sample data and ratio cols are removed here
DT <- dat[, .SD, .SDcols=m_island_id_1:groupsize]

#clean up names
rename <- c("Sum_nc","Sum_ic")
setnames(DT, rename, paste0(rename, "_1"))

#input ic, nc and output ratio columns
jcols <- 1:28
ic_cols <- paste0("Sum_ic_", jcols)
nc_cols <- paste0("Sum_nc_", jcols)
ratio_cols <- paste0("Ratio_nc_to_ic_", jcols)
```